# Capture image on server side volume with WDS on Server 2012 R2 (VMware ESXi)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, deployment, wds, image

I have an ESXi virtual machine running Windows Server 2012 and WDS.  The server VM has a secondary hard disk which is storing my boot and install image files.

When I try to capture an image, it wants me to save it to a local drive on the reference machine but for practicality's sake, I'd like to avoid having to truck a USB drive to each system I need to capture.  There will be a few...

Is there a way I can capture directly to my servers secondary HDD?  How else can I get the image to my server without physical presence or interaction on the remote machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't capture the image to a network location, only to a locally attached drive (the captured image will be uploaded to the WDS server after the capture). If the volume you're capturing is large enough you can capture the image to the volume that's being captured, which would eliminate the need to attach an external USB drive to the source machine.

Comment: Ah that would probably work in the majority of my cases.  I guess I saw that in my reading somewhere but didn't think about it.  I'm testing right now so fingers crossed!

Comment: Sorry, got caught up after my testing.  You were correct though.  I could save the captured .wim file to the local machines HDD.  I'll have to account for how I deal with transferring them to a central store after the capture but I should be able to manage that.

Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help...